# Programatically sort choices in a list field

Tags: list, powershell

I'm updating choices in a list field and want them to be stored alphabetically, however when I try to sort the choices I get the following error:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "mysite"
$list = $web.GetList("/list/url/AllItems.aspx")
$field = $list.Fields["File Under"]
$field.choices.add("NewItem")
$field.choices = $field.choices | sort

"Choices" is a ReadOnly property.
At line: 1 char:8
+ $field. <<<< choices = $field.choices | sort
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this neither in powershell nor in C# code.Ideally you should sort values while displaying .

Create a temporary array, add all the choice fields, sort it and remove previous values in SharePoint and again add the new values :-P

Comment: So I'm clear, you're saying I should create a sorted temporary array, then remove all the choices from the field, and re-add the choices from the temporary array in the new order?

Comment: yes, that's correct. But before implementing this on prod environment. Check what happens to the old records. I have not tried this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy you can do somethinf like this:

```
$field = $list.Fields["Test"] 
 $xmlSource = $field.SchemaXml
 $xmlData = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::Parse($xmlSource)
 $choicesParent=$xmlData.Element("CHOICES")
 $allchoices=$choicesParent.Elements("CHOICE")
 $allchoices = $allchoices|Sort-Object -Property Value
 $choicesParent.RemoveAll()
 $allchoices|foreach{$choicesParent.Add($_)}
$field.SchemaXml=$xmlData.ToString()
$field.Update();
```